# Display screen on [desk|lap]top

Tags: usb, remote-access

Is it possible to display the screen of my Android on a regular computer in a similar fashion as an emulator would ­– but with an actual device being displayed rather than an emulation? I am looking to plug my Android in and then do all phone activity on it from this imagined piece of software, such as use apps, send text messages and even make phone calls. E.g. when I am sitting at a computer, which offers far more UX convenience than a small Android device, I do not see why I wouldn't use it to augment the phone display on a much bigger monitor and use my keyboard instead if the phone is plugged in.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en) lets you use your computer's keyboard: